# Retroactivly add "am" or "pm" to an excel column

Tags: excel

I have a column in excel that is a bunch of times something was done. I didn't put AM or PM, but I know every time the actions were done it was between 6am and 5pm. How would I make a formula that takes the whole column, figures out if its am or pm, then puts that on the end of the times?

[A small part of the mentioned column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAxbk.png)

Comment: Using `HOUR` maybe and adding .5  if the hour is <= 5, assuming that all the times are currently AM.

Comment: Did you try changing the format to `hh:mm:ss AM/PM`

Comment: @ScottCraner i could, but then it wouldn't "know" if its supposed to be AM or PM, I'm working with 2k rows so i cannot manually input

Comment: @ParkerCole - datetimes are just numbers so the formatting doesn't change the underlying value. Changing the format is necessary though, and will also show you whether you need to modify the underlyling value.

Answer (score 0):

From your statement, you will NOT have any AM times that start with 1-5, or any PM times that start with 6 or above hours.  If this is indeed the case, insert a cheater column. In the top row, `=IF(AND(HOUR(A1)>=1,HOUR(A1)<=5),A1+0.5,A1)`  (obviously edit for the appropriate column the data is in).  Change the format on the new column to `Number/Time/1:30 PM`.  Then copy, paste values the new column.

Comment: Or more simply: `=IF(HOUR(A1)<=5,0.5,0)+A1`. You don't want the `>=1` check as that will not change a time such as `12:00 AM` to `12:00 PM`.

Comment: Totally right!   It's late, I'm tired, and made it more complicated.